# Checksum Calculation for bits

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am sure this will be simple for most experts on here. I have a few binary strings, the last of which is a checksum. I am trying to reproduce the calc to get the checksum, but I am unable to get there. I have tried and looked at many of the posts relating to checksum on here as well.

Here is the bitstring, spaced in groups of 8: 01010000 10000000 01100111 11110110
(11110110) should be the checksum. For testing I have done this:

```
def checksum(bytes):
    return (sum(bytes) & 0xFF)

def bitstring_to_bytes(s):
    v = int(s, 2)
    b = bytearray()
    while v:
        b.append(v & 0xff)
        v >>= 8
    return bytes(b[::-1])

t= ('010100001000000001100111') #left out the checksum as expected

bytes = bitstring_to_bytes(t)
print('bytes = %s' % bytes)

checksum_bytes = checksum(bytes)

checksum_bytes = checksum_bytes | 0xf0
checksum_bytes = bin(checksum_bytes)

print('checksum =%s' % checksum_bytes)
```

The above gets close with 11110111 vice 11110110. The last bit is off.

Comment: Why do you assume "the checksum" should be 11110110? Is it intentional that `bytes` is a sequence of `byte`s whereas `checksum_bytes` is an integer / sequence of bits?

Comment: The bitstring is from a documented RF signal and that is definitely the checksum. I have tried calculating the checksum in a variety of ways, but this was the closest. I am open to trying anything suggested, given the 5hours I spent trying to get it to work last night

Comment: How is the checksum computed? There is more than one definition of "check sum" in coding theory.

Comment: @JohnColeman in the C code I am working from, they are using lfsr. I have also looked at that here, and tried a variety of things (but I also likely did that incorrectly). Here is the C with lfsr: lfsr_digest8(b, 3, 0x98, 0xf1);

Where B is the bitstring as I wrote it at the start, grouped in 8 bits. I assume 0x98 would be the seed

Comment: Something implicitly defined in some C code that we can't see doesn't give adequate information about what you are trying to compute. If this is some sort of standard checksum scheme, can you provide e.g. a link to a Wikipedia article that defines it?

Comment: I edited to add more clarity once I realized that. But the only thing I can work from is found here https://github.com/merbanan/rtl_433/blob/master/src/devices/acurite.c in the funct: static int acurite_606_decode(r_device *decoder, bitbuffer_t *bitbuffer)
{

Comment: That github is 2000 lines of code, most of which seems devoted to decoding. It isn't clear which of those 2000 lines you are trying to port to python. The `11110111` that your code comes up with is the `or` of the other bytes. That seems reasonable enough. Why are you sure that it is wrong?

Comment: @JohnColeman I am positive its wrong because I have the expected checksum of 11110110, and a transmission of the bitstring and the expected checksum is recognized by rtl433, while a transmission of the bitstring with the checksum I did is not recognized and fails on the checksum.

Guess I will keep looking

Comment: Have you run the C code to see what it produces in this case?